# Google cloud 'http' does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I try to run my google cloud application in the localhost and need to use 'http' due to SSL issues. But when I try to sign in, I get this error.

[image]

What I try to do is add the URI to the OAuth client, but the problem is that it does not let me add 'http' to the OAuth. I can add 'https' but that does not work.

Is there a way that i can register 'http' on google cloud or is there another workaround?

Comment: You can add `http://localhost:8081/oauth2callback` to the Redirect URI. Try again and add more information to your question.

Comment: add it to the redirect URI in my code or google cloud?

Comment: In Google Client Secrets, the Redirect URI must match your code exactly. You need to configure both. This is a security measure. Only authorized Redirect URIs can receive the OAuth 2 Code.